# SAS Graph - Values of a variable for axis1 tick marks

Tags: sas

In SAS graph, I have a graph that expresses axis2 with dates(Batch_date) from 6/24/2015 to 12/8/2015 in 6 day increments. If I use the statement -

```
proc gplot data=datasets.x_batch;
plot 

prcnt_10*batch_date=1
prcnt_20*batch_date=2 
prcnt_30*batch_date=3
prcnt_40*batch_date=4
prcnt_50*batch_date=5
prcnt_60*batch_date=6
prcnt_70*batch_date=7
prcnt_80*batch_date=8
prcnt_90*batch_date=9
prcnt_100*batch_date=10
prcnt_110*batch_date=11
prcnt_120*batch_date=12....
```

It creates my plot successfully, but the tick marks seem to be notated with default values (6/16,7/1...etc). I understand how to control the tick marks with the `minor=(n=n h=n) and major=(h=n)` but it still chooses different values to display on the major tick marks.

Is there a way to explicitly assign each tick mark label (or better yet, just call out the date variable values for the tick mark labels) with out explicitely stating each date value in an `(order)` statement?

Comment: You should be able to use the START to END BY INTERVAL notation in an axis statement.

Comment: Statement of axis2 minor=(n=5 h=3) order=('30jun2015'd to '08dec2015'd by 7) did what I needed, unfortunately the dates came out vertical...just looks odd. Is there a simple way to transpose the labels so they would display horizontally?

Comment: Look for an angle option in the docs.

Comment: I must have an error in this - "axis1 label=('% Cured');
axis2 minor=(n=6 h=1)major=(h=2) 
   order=('30jun2015'd to '08dec2015'd by 7)
   label=('Batch End Date')
   angle=75
   ;"

Comment: You're almost there, move the ANGLE inside a VALUE option, like this: axis2 minor=(n=6 h=1) major=(h=2) order=('30jun2015'd to '08dec2015'd by 7) label=('Batch End Date')   value=(angle=75) ;

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!